Terraform - Try to Create an Azure SQL Connection V2 not V1
I am using Terraform to create the infrastructure layer of the solution on Azure.
The below code creates a SQL Connection in Azure however its V1 I want V2 and set ‘Authentication = ManagedIdentity’- how to modify the below?
# Create Azure API Connection SQL Connection. This is used by the Logic-App to query the Azure SQL databases.
resource "azapi_resource" "sql_conn" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01"
  name      = local.sql_connection
  parent_id = data.azurerm_resource_group.solution_rg.id
  location  = var.location
  tags      = local.tags

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      displayName = "${local.sql_connection}"
      statuses = [
        {
          "status" : "Connected"
        }
      ]

      parameterValues = {
        name   = "managedIdentityAuth"
        #values = {}
      }

      api = {
        name        = "sql"
        displayName = "SQL Server"
        description = "Microsoft SQL Server is a relational database management system developed by Microsoft. Connect to SQL Server to manage data. You can perform various actions such as create, update, get, and delete on rows in a table."
        iconUri     = "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1686/1.0.1686.3706/sql/icon.png"
        brandColor  = "#ba141a"
        id          = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/uksouth/managedApis/sql"
        type        = "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
      }
    }
  })
}


Currently Authenatication...

Authenatication Required...


This worked - v2 and managed indentity...sensitive values modified...
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "api_sql_connection2" {
  name                = "${local.sql_api_connection}-3"
  resource_group_name = local.solution_rg
  tags                = local.tags
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental" # DO NOT CHANGE OTHERWISE YOU CAN ACCIDENTLY DELETE AZ RESOURCES
  template_content    = <<TEMPLATE
  {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [{
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "kind": "V2",
      "properties": {
          "displayName": "api_sql_connection",
          "authenticatedUser": {},
          "overallStatus": "Ready",
          "statuses": [
              {
                  "status": "Ready"
              }
          ],
          "connectionState": "Enabled",
          "parameterValueSet": {
              "name": "oauthMI",
              "values": {}
          },
          "customParameterValues": {},
          "createdTime": "2024-07-01T08:11:41.176Z",
          "changedTime": "2024-07-03T07:36:09.333Z",
          "api": {
              "name": "sql",
              "displayName": "SQL Server",
              "description": "Microsoft SQL Server is a relational database management system developed by Microsoft. Connect to SQL Server to manage data. You can perform various actions such as create, update, get, and delete on rows in a table.",
              "iconUri": "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1686/1.0.1686.3706/sql/icon.png",
              "brandColor": "#ba141a",
              "category": "Standard",
              "id": "/subscriptions/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/uksouth/managedApis/sql",
              "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
          },
          "testLinks": [
              {
                  "requestUri": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/abc/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql/extensions/proxy/testconnection?api-version=2018-07-01-preview",
                  "method": "get"
              }
          ],
          "testRequests": [
              {
                  "body": {
                      "request": {
                          "method": "get",
                          "path": "testconnection"
                      }
                  },
                  "inputParameters": [
                      {
                          "path": "body.properties.workflowReference.id",
                          "type": "string",
                          "description": "The workflow reference resource id."
                      }
                  ],
                  "requestUri": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/abc/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql/dynamicInvoke?api-version=2018-07-01-preview",
                  "method": "POST"
              }
          ],
          "connectionRuntimeUrl": "https://38d4602d576749ad.06.common.logic-uksouth.azure-apihub.net/apim/sql/909f2a0112b3473abca8ab59120da340"
      },
      "id": "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/abc/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
      "name": "sql",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "location": "uksouth"
    }]
}
TEMPLATE
}

